# Clustered indexes as PK or PK that is created using FK's (as a serial number)

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, clustered-index

I'm creating a database that will be used for a web app for editing and preview of a Monthly Work Schedule. The principle behind this is to make a highly flexible layout that will provide building blocks for filtering, preview, and the making of templates.

The way it works:
    There are 10 tables - each has a pretty simple data structure (ID, ShortName, Descr).
    I want to make a table that will exclusively use data that already exists in those tables and save those combinations as new schedules.
    So, you pre-make all the elements and then you put them together like Legos for final product/schedule. 
    **Important - I want to enforce 7 tables- Center, Rank, Role, One, Two, Year, Month. Without all those selected (or if duplicate) you can't save/create a new schedule.**

Now, I have two dilemmas here:
    1. Should I create clustered indexes from those values like in the image
    2. Should I make PK - and make it like serial number so that it's incremented using the data from those tables, e.g. Center(01) + Rank(02) + Role(12) + One(15) + Two(01) + Year(2019) + Month (07) = 0102121501201907

[image: example visual diagram]

Also, another dilemma is Year/Month entry
**I need JUST Year and JUST Month as Columns and values.** Which way would be recommended here?
Can I make a Custom Data Type that will trim month and day from date to have just Year?
Should I define Year as int and make a defined table with Months (ID, Name)?

**I can't go with a date because I need Year and Month as individual constraining parameters.** I don't need Days - and removing day value from a date format through functions and user interface sounds like too much work for something that should be relatively simple. (performance-wise) 
Also, making Year and Month as int and defining 12 Months - I'm afraid I'll lose some functionality just because I'm not familiar enough to use it.

This is my first work of this kind, and I feel like these decisions will heavily influence everything I do onward, so any advice whether from experience or from theory/book/site is highly appreciated.

Comment: How would you enforce the relationship between the project table and the supporting tables if you mash all the IDs into one serial number? Joining on those tables would be difficult

Comment: I worked on a prod DB where serial key was actually a mashup consisted of 5 values that exist in other tables + increment value. 
e.g. typeid(2356)+timing(1234)+pos(0004)+incrementvalue(0001) = 2356123400040001. 
if you don't have all the elements serial can't be created hence you can't save/make new entry. but to be honest - i would have to research that mechanism more in order to know if it's applicable here that's why i'm asking for advice before i make this more complicated than i should. 
maybe i'm just blind to a simpler solution

Comment: I was asking in practical terms as to how you will use this data. So you have your project table and you need to know the name of the center that each project is at. Using both models how would you do it? How often would you do it? How much data would you do it with? That would drive my decision making

Comment: e.g. there are ~100 teams, each with their own city, ranks, roles - they all need to have a monthly schedule. once the schedule is made the only write actions will be Vac, PL, Blood Leave etc - i will have all those defined in one table, and the user will be able to apply those values where needed. 

3 tables on the right have actual "building blocks for the schedule - the tables on the left + year, Month have to serve as a constraint because i don't want a schedule to miss any of those key defining parameters - i need those parameters to serve as my PK in a way because they will be unique.

Comment: that means ~100 January 2020 schedules, ~100 February 2020 schedules and so on. but the number of schedules will match the number of total teams that exist. once that month is gone, that schedule becomes history for review but not any kind of editing.      I was thinking to have that table (if i do this approach), close like every 6 months for example and a new one is made to store next 6 months